# How should I use JQuery to change the background color of a DOM element on mouse over?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, onmouseover

Is it possible to execute jQuery's code in a link? For example, can I do this?

```
<a href="index.php" onmouseover="$(this).css("background-color","#111111");">Home</a>
```

I want use this for in some links create some effect and not touch more CSS.

Comment: why don't you use `a:hover`?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: No happened nothing no change color

Comment: If you change your code like <a href="index.php" onmouseover="$(this).css('background-color','red');">Home</a> will work. Please see the difference in using quotes.

Comment: It is generally bad form to use JQuery inline.  JQuery was meant to be an unobtrusive framework meaning not requiring additional text to your DOM.  You would want to do this using an event binding on a selector... NOT inline.

Answer (score 2):

You're closing the attribute quotation marks with the quotes in the JavaScript.

Either escape them,

```
onmouseover="$(this).css(\"background-color\",\"#111111\");"
```

or use single quotes for the inner or outer.

```
onmouseover='$(this).css("background-color","#111111");'
```

Comment: If you're going to use JQuery you **SHOULD NOT** be using onmouseover!  You should be using the JQuery events to map what you want not obtrusive DOM events.

Answer (score 1):

You want this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
     $("a").hover(
       function () {
         $(this).addClass("hover");
       },
       function () {
         $(this).removeClass("hover");
       }
     );
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.hover{
     background-color: #111111;
}
</style>

<a href="index.php">Home</a>
```

You can find additional resources at:  http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('a').hover(function() {
    // on hover
    $(this).css("background-color","#111111");
  }, function() {
    // on mouse leave
    // code
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="index.php" onmouseover="$(this).css('background-color','red');">Home</a>` will work.

You used to `onmouseover="$(this).css("background-color","#111111");"`

I used `onmouseover="$(this).css('background-color','red');"`

Demo is present at http://jsfiddle.net/2dJAN/44/

Note: You can use like http://jsfiddle.net/2dJAN/45/